# Increment attributes of a datetime Series in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime, python-datetime

I have a Series containing `datetime64[ns]` elements called `series`, and would like to increment the months. I thought the following would work fine, but it doesn't:

```
    series.dt.month += 1
```

The error is

```
    ValueError: modifications to a property of a datetimelike object are not supported. Change values on the original.
```

Is there a simple way to achieve this without needing to redefine things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I created timeseries date example:

```
import datetime
t = [datetime.datetime(2015,4,18,23,33,58),datetime.datetime(2015,4,19,14,32,8),datetime.datetime(2015,4,20,18,42,44),datetime.datetime(2015,4,20,21,41,19)]
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(t,columns=['Date'])
```

Timeseries:

```
df
Out[]: 
                 Date
0 2015-04-18 23:33:58
1 2015-04-19 14:32:08
2 2015-04-20 18:42:44
3 2015-04-20 21:41:19
```

Now increment part, you can use offset option.

```
df['Date']+pd.DateOffset(days=30)
```

Output:

```
df['Date']+pd.DateOffset(days=30)
Out[66]: 
0   2015-05-18 23:33:58
1   2015-05-19 14:32:08
2   2015-05-20 18:42:44
3   2015-05-20 21:41:19
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```